# Is it weird to a add ", please." at the end of a sentence in emails?

Tags: email

I have recently joined a new company and realized that there are some employees fond of adding ", please" at the end of a sentence in emails, e.g.

> I would like to send you the files in PDF format for your easy reference, please.

> For your information, please.

Although I think the usage is weird, I did send "FYI, please." to my boss one time because it seems more polite to me than just "FYI."

Still, the whole **please** thing seems weird to me. Is it grammatically incorrect?

Comment: I don't know that it's grammatically incorrect, but it does seem weird. Note that it is possible for a sentence to be both grammatically correct and nonsensical.

Comment: There's nothing ungrammatical about it; it's just being extra polite. "I would like to send you X _if I may_, or _if that's all right with you_."

Comment: Typically when you do a _For your information_ email, you're doing the recipient a favor by giving them information that they might not otherwise have received. Since you are not requesting any action from them, there's no need to include a 'please'.

Comment: I think you're right, though-- it sounds a bit weird.  I personally have never seen that (at least not as a regular thing).

Comment: 'Please' may be avoided here, unless the writer seeks a recommendation, reference or so.  Use of 'please' at the end of sentences works to dilute an imperative tone.  "Please wait outside." is rude unlike "Wait outside, please" which is a little toned down.

Answer (score 1):

***"Weird"*** is when you are woken in the night by the sound of strange music, you look out the window and you see flying turtles landing - that's "weird".

I confess to hyperbole.

However the OED's first sense of the word is:

> 1. Having the power to control the fate or destiny of human beings, etc.; later, claiming the supernatural power of dealing with fate or
>      destiny.

Later senses and examples are slightly more everyday, but the most urbane example of "weird" I was able to find in the OED was:

> 1855 C. Dickens Holly-tree Inn: Guest in Househ. Words Extra
>   Christmas No. 5/2 He was a man with a weird belief in him that no one
>   could count the stones of Stonehenge twice, and make the same number
>   of them.

So writing "please" at the end of a sentence hardly qualifies as "weird" I would maintain.

**Nonetheless, I do agree that using "please" in the way you describe is non-idiomatic.**

My own way of giving that expression would be something like:

*Please find attached the files for your information* or

*I have pleasure in attaching the files you require*.

Comment: How often do people use *weird* as per the definition you quoted? In my experience most people use it as a synonym for *strange*. I suspect a lot of people aren't even aware of the supernatural sense.

Comment: @nnnnnn Increasingly too often I fear. And simply because people cannot be troubled to enlarge the scope of their vocabulary. In this and a vast number of other ways English is being dumbed down.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a weird form of communication if it fits in with the company culture. Culture is defined as: [the ideas, customs, and social behaviour of a particular people or society (https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=define+culture).

This use of language may be classed as company culture. Company culture refers to the attitudes and behaviors of a company and its employees. It is evident in the way an organization's people interact with each other, the values they hold, and the decisions they make (Google: define company culture).

Saying that, the sentence "I would like to send you the files in PDF format for your easy reference, please" may suggest that a little 'sorry for the trouble this may cause you' is involved.

Alternatively, if the sentence originates from someone who is bilingual, it may be a direct translation from their mother tongue, where 'please' and 'thank you' have a similar meaning. It may also be polite to say 'please' at the end of a request.

For instance, the Italian word'ciao', used colloquially, may mean 'hello' or 'goodbye'.